# Can I delete older .AndroidStudioX.Y folders on Windows safely?

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

I've installed the latest version of Android Studio (version 3.0). Yet for some reason other versions of Android Studio still exist under my user folder:

[image]

Can I safely delete these folders without any side effect?

I also don't need that AndroidStudioProjects folder and have never created a project in it. But it also takes around 1 Gigabytes of space. Can I delete that too?

All I want now is my Android Studio 3.0 to be working flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

The folders labeled `.AndroidStudioX.Y` only contain preferences and settings for the Android Studio IDE. They can be deleted at any time and Android Studio will still be runnable, but previous settings may be lost. As long as you selected "import previous settings" when updating Android Studio, deleting folders from older versions will do no harm at all.

The `AndroidStudioProjects` folder is exactly what it describes; by default, projects will be placed here. It can be deleted if there are no projects you care about in it. However, if you have not created a project in the folder, I am curious what is inside it that is taking up so much space.